Adjective placement - why do I sometimes see "meat raw" instead of "raw meat"?
What's the meaning of "meat raw".
For example:

You should not eat meat raw.

Why not "raw meat"?

Please quote the sentence so that we can help you better.

By "pages" do you mean web pages? Examples would make it clear how that should be understood, e.g. here the sentence "Eating meat raw, ..." is to be understood as "Eating meat that is raw, ...". Please add your examples to your question by editing it.

See also "people angry with high prices" "a sticky note attached", "using the methods selected", etc

It's the difference between attributive adjectives and predicative adjectives.
Attributive adjectives go before the noun and modify it - "raw meat" is an example of this. The meat is raw.
Predicative adjectives go after the noun and indicate the state of something in the context of the statement. In a statement like "I don't eat meat raw", the predicative adjective describes the state the meat is in when eating.

Sorry, but raw meat is attributive? raw is a normal adjective, not attributive though raw can be a noun as in The Raw and The Cooked by Claude Lévi-Strauss....

@Lambie I don't think you've understood my answer at all. It can be either. It depends where it is placed, how it is used.

No, you didn't understand my comment. I know raw can be a noun, which is why I cited the book. But raw meat and cooked meat are adjectival. In the meat is raw, it is raw meat, there is nothing attributive about it at all.

@Lambie - From this reference: "An attributive adjective is an adjective that is directly adjacent to the noun or pronoun it modifies. An attributive adjective is not separated from a noun by a linking verb. In English, attributive adjectives usually come directly before the noun they modify." Under this definition, the "raw" in the noun phrase "raw meat" is unquestionably an attributive adjective.

@lambie You do know that raw meat can become cooked meat, right? You cook it, it ceases to be raw. So being 'raw' isn't a permanent attribute. Saying "never drink cow's milk" is different - the milk cannot become that of another animal. So it isn't always possible for an adjective to be used differently, but in this case, it is. Read my answer a third time, see if you get it now.

@Astralbee - I suspect that Lambie's confusion stems from having heard of attributive nouns, but then incorrectly thinking that only nouns can be called "attributive" when they modify the primary noun in a noun phrase. Thus their repeated emphasis on how "raw" isn't a noun in this instance.

@CanadianYankee Yes, that's right and if this is CGEL, I find it completely confusing for learners. Thank you for your lucid comment. It's unbelievable that this person thinks "I don't understand it". Gees. It's just a regular adjective, preceding a noun. Since nouns can be used attributively as adjective, I find it confusing.

@Lambie - It's not confusing: an attributive word or expression is anything (including an adjective!) within a noun phrase that modifies the main noun. It can be an attributive adjective, as in "raw meat"; or an attributive noun, as in "dog meat"; or a more complicated attributive expression, as in "well-past-its-sell-by-date meat".  An adjective used outside of a noun phrase is still "normal" in that it modifies a noun, but it's no longer attributive. See here for a reference on this for learners.

@CanadianYankee And I think to edit the question with an entirely different thing is not helpful. Astralbee changed the question which was "meat raw", which cannot stand on its own to "not eat one's meat raw". But that is not the mistake as posted by the OP who obviously is clueless. So changing everything to suit one's idea of what the question should be, is over the top.
